# boost::filesystem::copy_file() missing symbol in c++11

Tags: boost, c++11

If Boost is compiled *without* C++11 support the `boost::filesystem` uses emulated scoped enumerators.  If you then take this built Boost and use it in a project *with* C++11 support you end up with a missing symbol because the declaration of `boost::filesystem::copy_file()` has changed.

There is an easy fix for this:

```
# if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#   define NO_SCOPED_ENUMS
# endif
# ifdef NO_SCOPED_ENUMS
#   if BOOST_VERSION < 105000
#     ifndef BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS
#       define BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS
#       define REMOVE
#     endif
#   else
#     ifndef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#       define BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#       define REMOVE
#     endif
#   endif
# endif
# include "boost/filesystem.hpp"
# if defined(NO_SCOPED_ENUMS) && defined(REMOVE)
#   undef REMOVE
#   if BOOST_VERSION < 105000
#     undef BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS
#   else
#     undef BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS
#   endif
# endif
```

This preprocess bit defines either the `BOOST_NO_SCOPED_ENUMS` or `BOOST_NO_CXX11_SCOPED_ENUMS` depending on the Boost version, includes `boost/filesystem` and then removes it again if it wasn't defined before (to be safe)

Now the issue here is that the scoped enumerators are turned off when we are compiling for C++11:

```
# if __cplusplus >= 201103L
#   define NO_SCOPED_ENUMS
# endif
```

However, if Boost has actually been compiled *with* C++11 support this will break again because the declaration will be changed.  It needs to be something like:

```
// BOOST_COMPILED_WITH_CXX11 doesn't exist
# if (__cplusplus >= 201103L) && !defined(BOOST_COMPILED_WITH_CXX11)
#   define NO_SCOPED_ENUMS
# endif
```

This is where my question comes in:

**tl;dr - Can I determine if Boost was compiled with C++11 support?**

The closest I've [found](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/config/doc/html/index.html#boost_config.configuring_boost_for_your_platform.using_the_configure_script) is:

> However you run the configure script, when it finishes you will find a new header -`user.hpp`- located in the `<boost-root>/libs/config/` directory. **Note that configure does not install this header into your boost include path by default**. This header contains all the options generated by the configure script, plus a header-section that contains the user settable options from the default version of  (located under /boost/config/).

Comment: In the fix above I had to remove if BOOST_VERSION < 105000, I used boost 1.56 and gcc 4.8.4 (linux mint 17).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You **don't** want to link a C++11 project with non-C++11 libraries. C++11 breaks binary compatibility and while things may work in most cases, it will bite you in the butt at some point.

See also [do we need to recompile libraries with c++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9408656/do-we-need-to-recompile-libraries-with-c11)

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If I understand that link correctly, they want to use C++11 which will require `gcc-4.7`+.  They already have binaries compiled with `4.2.1`.  They will have to recompile the binaries regardless of using C++11 or not because they are changing between a major release of gcc (which the gcc developers regard as a change in the major or minor release numbers)

Comment: I have to confess that I didn't read the link thoroughly, I should have :). In any case, compiling a project with gcc-4.7 with --stdc++11, and linking with a library compiled with gcc-4.7 without --std=c++11 is not a good idea. Consider also that some headers may have pre-processor #if's based on whether C++11 support is available or not. Those #if's will evaluate differently when compiling the C++11 project compared to the C++03 library. Which may or may not break compatibility. This goes as well for mixing release and debug builds.

Comment: Don't worry, I agree with you - Just clarifying the link ;)