# Got error when install mongodb on centos 6.5(64bits)

Tags: linux, mongodb, centos

I am installing mongodb on CentOS 6.4, but have following error:

```
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.0.1-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.0)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit)
Error: Package: mongodb-org-server-3.0.1-1.amzn1.x86_64 (mongodb-org-3.0)
           Requires: libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How can I install that library. Thank you

Comment: Do you understand what the error message said?

Comment: How can I install that library?

Comment: try this `yum search compat-libstdc++ `

Comment: i installed compat-libstdc but when i write: 
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX ==> then
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
There is no GLIBCXX_3.4.14 and GLIBCXX_3.4.15

Comment: Might well be better to ask on http://www.serverfault.com SO is aimed at solving programming questions, in a rather narrow sense. Flagging for migration.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386651/how-to-fix-usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found

Comment: Thanks for all. I dit it. That's because the old gcc version.

Comment: @Mr.Dung I have the same problem. Could you please post how you solved it as an answer? Thank you

Comment: I did follow the article: [link](http://wiki.mikejung.biz/Gcc_CentOS)

Answer (score 0):

Run **package-cleanup --problems** to list all dependencies and then install those dependencies.