# how to find libstdc++.so.6: that contain GLIBCXX_3.4.19 for RHEL 6?

Tags: linux, tensorflow, libstdc++, rhel6

I work with a Linuxs server:

```
> cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)
```

(from wikipedia:
***Red Hat Enterprise Linux 6*** was forked from ***Fedora 12***

```
6.7, also termed Update 7, 22 July 2015 (kernel 2.6.32-573)
6.8, also termed Update 8, 10 May 2016 (kernel 2.6.32-642))
```

The kernel

```
> uname -r
2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64

> uname -s
Linux

> uname -v
#1 SMP Tue Nov 15 22:57:18 EST 2016

> cat /proc/version
Linux version 2.6.32-642.11.1.el6.x86_64 (sandman@node3res7) (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (SuSE 4.4.7-17) (GCC) ) 
#1 SMP Tue Nov 15 22:57:18 EST 2016
```

gcc version

```
> gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 4.4.7 20120313 (SuSE 4.4.7-17)
```

when trying to install Tensdorflow, I have some issue with a missing library:

```
ImportError: /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /opt/ccda/anaconda2/envs/tensorflow35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow.so)
```

As you can see in my ***lib64/libstdc++.so.6*** I don't have ***GLIBCXX_3.4.19***

```
strings /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4 
GLIBCXX_3.4.1  
....  
GLIBCXX_3.4.12  
GLIBCXX_3.4.13  
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW  
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

I look with the following command:

```
yum whatprovides */libstdc++.so.6
...
libstdc++-4.4.7-17.el6.x86_64 : GNU Standard C++ Library
Repo        : installed
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6
```

so my question where can I find the ***libstdc++-4.x.y-z.el6.x86_64*** that contain ***GLIBCXX_3.4.19*** and that I could install on my server RHEL 6  with my gcc version ?

I am a little bit confuse of which version to use from this page
[https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libstdc%2B%2B.so.6%28GLIBCXX_3.4.19%29&submit=Search+...&system=&arch=](https://www.rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=libstdc%2B%2B.so.6%28GLIBCXX_3.4.19%29&submit=Search%20...&system=&arch=)

1. I don't see a version for Fedora 12 or RHEL6
2. I need arch x86_64
3. I need I guess something  gcc (GCC) 4.4.7
4. I guess I need 64bit

I the following a good macth ? I am quite confuse by the name and info:

```
libstdc++6-gcc48-32bit-4.8.5-21.1.x86_64.html   The standard C++ shared library OpenSuSE leap updates for 42.1  libstdc++6-gcc48-32bit-4.8.5-21.1.x86_64.rpm
```

I don't have Internet access on the server so I need to download the file locally copy it on the server and do the intsallion.

Thanks for your help
Cheers
Fabien

ps: bonus question
SuSE 4.4.7-17 (GCC), I am confuse, I understood that Suse was a Linux distribution like Redhat!

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution here:
https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/red-hat-31/lib-libstdc-so-6-version-%60glibcxx_3-4-15'-not-found-4175419985/

> Replacing libstdc++-so.6 with a later version that works in EL6:
>   Unpack libstdc++6_4.7.1-2_i386.deb
>   http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool...7.1-2_i386.deb
>   with : ar -x libstdc++6_4.7.1-2_i386.deb && tar xvf data.tar.gz
>   Next : 1) su ; 2) cp libstdc++.so.6.0.17 /usr/lib/
>   3) cd /usr/lib/ && rm libstdc++.so.6
>   4) ln -s libstdc++.so.6.17 libstdc++.so.6
>
> Reason for suggesting the Debian package :
>   It's a ( gcc ) libstdc++ version that's compiled with a glibc
>   old enough to be used in EL6 / CentOS 6.

Answer (score 3):

Updated steps (because it seems the file has been moved):

```
curl -O http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.7/libstdc++6-4.7-dbg_4.7.2-5_i386.deb
tar -x libstdc++6-4.7-dbg_4.7.2-5_i386.deb && tar xvf data.tar.gz
mkdir backup
cp /usr/lib/libstdc++.so* backup/
cp ./usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/debug/libstdc++.so.6.0.17 /usr/lib
ln -s libstdc++.so.6.0.17 libstdc++.so.6
```

Answer (score 2):

Previous link is dead now as well, you can use this one

```
http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/gcc-4.8/libstdc++6-4.8-dbg_4.8.4-1_i386.deb
```

In previous comment from Serge, there's a `cd` missing
    cd /usr/lib/
Or like in my case
    cd /usr/lib64

Comment: OP is clearly directed to centos (RHEL) systems.So this won't help.

Comment: The link in Serge's comment doesn't work anymore but his post has the instructions, whereas this post provides the link. So it is still useful.

Answer (score 0):

For RHEL6, this is in the Software Collections.

I think (without citation) the devtoolsets are numbered according to what version gcc is included. devtoolset 8 will give you gcc 8. Much higher than 4.7 or 4.8.

```
subscription-manager repos --enable rhel-server-dts-6-rpms
yum install devtoolset-8-gcc-c++
source scl_source enable devtoolset-8
```