# Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime after following the installation instructions

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, syntaxnet

I'm trying to install SyntaxNet on Ubuntu, I followed the Ubuntu 16.10+ binary installation instruction [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/syntaxnet). When I ran the last command:

```
python -c 'import dragnn.python.load_dragnn_cc_impl, syntaxnet.load_parser_ops'
```

I get this long line of error message below:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/dragnn/python/load_dragnn_cc_impl.py", line 19, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 52, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 41, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.22' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so)


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

I checked the common installation problems page but it appears there is no fix for this there yet. Does anyone have a similar problem installing SyntaxNet? I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install latest libstdc++6.

1. check version

   > strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep  GLIBCXX
2. add repo

   > sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
3. install

   > sudo apt-get update
   >   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade  # I used this command, I guess that the following command should also work.
   >
   > sudo apt-get install libstdc++6

I followed this: [How to fix: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19386651/how-to-fix-usr-lib-libstdc-so-6-version-glibcxx-3-4-15-not-found).

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything seems to be working now